# How to create a method that takes an integer array of any length as its only parameter, and returns a new integer array that has a length of only 2

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone here help me with this ? I need a method that takes an integer array of any length as its only parameter, and returns a new integer array that has a length of only 2.

This is what i have so far:

```
public static int[] GetHiLo(int[] values)
{
    int [] values = int{1,2,3,4};
}
```

Comment: `public int[] YourMethod(int[] input) { return new int[] {0, 0}; }`

Comment: please state clearly your question, add some sample input and the output you expect, and the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, this is the best you can get:

```
public int[] DoSomething(int[] inputArray)
{
    int[] retVal = new int[2];
    //Do something with the input array
    return retVal;
}
```

It takes any length as the input array and returns a 2 item array. You can index through it like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
{
    int something = inputArray[i];
}
```

or

```
foreach (int value in inputArray)
{
    int something = value;
}
```

**Edit**

To do your actual task, you can do something like:

```
public int[] GetHighLow(int[] inputArray)
{
    int[] retVal = new int[2];
    int highest = inputArray[0];
    int lowest = inputArray[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (inputArray[i] > highest)
            highest = inputArray[i];
        if (inputArray[i] < lowest)
            lowest = inputArray[i];
    }

    retVal[0] = highest; 
    retVal[1] = lowest;

    return retVal;
}
```

Please take some time to understand exactly how the function works. It compares a value against all the items in the array to see which one is highest or lowest by comparing them to saved values.

Comment: Write a method called GetHiLo() that takes an integer array of any length as its only parameter, and returns a new integer array that has a length of only 2. The first value in the new array that is returned is the highest value in the array that was passed, and the second value is the lowest value in the array that was passed. You can assume the array that is passed has at least one element in it.

Comment: Please give it a try, I'm not really wanting to do your homework. Let us know when you get stuck, but at least put some code on the screen to see if you can make it work.

Comment: This is what i have so far:     public static int[] GetHiLo(int[] values)
{

int [] values = int{1,2,3,4};




}

Comment: @NnachetaNnyagu you should edit your original question with the code you have, don't post it as a comment here.